# Unity rotation on hills

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, path-finding

Hello im not that new to unity but i want to achive this :
[image]

I have no idea how many people say ik but its too complex and some say with Quaternion but they dont explain how shoud i do it so if someone has a idea please share thank you . Im using A* pathfinding and using the example AI they have i tried using AIlerp that does what i want but it has alot of bugs :)

Comment: Could you add any sample/fragment you tried already?

Comment: Assuming you haven't even tried anything, you could start by rotating the character object by the angle of the objects up vector and the normal of the surface its "standing" on (standing meaning, raycast downwards from the object). It's simple and ugly, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the surface normal and apply it to the object.
First find the vector that goes from point A to point B, rotate it by 90 degrees and finally normalize it.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
Vector3 pointA = new Vector3(x,y,z);
Vector3 pointB = new Vector3(x,y,z);

Vector3 dir = pointB - pointA;
Vector3 normal = new Vector3(-dir.y, dir.x).normalized;

object.transform.up = normal;
```